# apt-get installation of nginx leaves files owned by root

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, system-administration, ownership

I'm coming to nginx after years of using apache httpd. I used apt-get to install the nginx server and notice that all the files are owned by root.

```
debian@nginx-explore:~$ ls -la /usr/share/nginx/www/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 23 21:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 21:09 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  383 Jul  7  2006 50x.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  151 Oct  4  2004 index.html
```

The master process is also owned by root, although there are worker processes running as www-data

```
debian@nginx-explore:~$ ps aux|grep nginx
root      2724  0.0  0.1  62348  1324 ?        Ss   Apr23   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  2725  0.0  0.1  62688  1624 ?        S    Apr23   0:03 nginx: worker process
www-data  2726  0.0  0.1  62688  1624 ?        S    Apr23   0:03 nginx: worker process
www-data  2727  0.0  0.1  62688  1624 ?        S    Apr23   0:03 nginx: worker process
www-data  2728  0.0  0.2  62688  2132 ?        S    Apr23   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

In Apache, it was always stressed to make sure files and processes were not owned by root as a security measure. Is there some reason this isn't a big deal when using nginx?

Ultimately I need to know whether I should go tweak the ownership for nginx files and folders to keep my system secure.

Comment: I noticed in Ubuntu 14.04 nginx log ownership was changed to root, so I'm wondering the same. It seems like a conscious decision made by the maintainers, but it has left me wondering the same as you. Perhaps serverfault will be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I just posted it http://serverfault.com/questions/592071/apt-get-installation-of-nginx-leaves-files-owned-by-root. That is probably where I should have started.

Answer (score 1):

Since the files are owned by root, the nginx user (www-data) responsible for handling web traffic has no ability through a security hole or otherwise to allow write access to the www files. Therefore, its following the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

Looking at it from the other side, if you changed the files to be owned by the nginx user (www-data), then it might be possible to exploit the nginx worker process to modify the files that it owns, in this case your www pages.